# Saving memory by hiding non-visible views?

Tags: objective-c, performance, uiview, hide

I've got just a short question, I'm using ARC and have multiple views in a horizontal scrollview. Does hiding non visible views save me some memory ? Or is there any other way to keep the performance of the app high?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it allows system to optimize memory usage during drawing. But usually more important is to set UIView as opaque if possible. It can increase performance and reduce memory usage

```
view.opaque = YES
```

> This property provides a hint to the drawing system as to how it
>   should treat the view. If set to YES, the drawing system treats the
>   view as fully opaque, which allows the drawing system to optimize some
>   drawing operations and improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can have high performance while having big allocation of data (i.e. memory) same goes for low performance with small amount if data (i.e. memory), so the question is what do you want to decrease/ increase and why.

in direct regards to your question
hiding a view doesn't free the memory, and keeps performance higher than delete the view and reallocate it, but deleting the view decrease the memory.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you please tell me, how to delete a view with arc?

Comment: if you create the view programmatically in a function then once the block is terminated and no other object is referencing that view the garbage collection will collect it. also by removing it from the viewcontroller like this `[subview removeFromSuperview]` last but not least you should take a look at creating a `@autoreleasepool` block